# What is the process to go through to find the right bundles to include in pom dependency?

Tags: maven, osgi, bundle

I am running into issues with the unresolved error in karaf.

```
<Embed-Dependency>!org.osgi.core,*,</Embed-Dependency>
<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
```

So pretty much everything gets put into bundle-classpath. However, I am finding some packages missing and unresolved when I deploy to karaf. 
I have not mentioned any dependency as "provided"

Some unresolved packages are:

javax.wsdl.extensions

org.relaxng.datatype

How do I go about figuring out what maven dependency to include in my pom to resolve this ?

Also, why do these still show up as un-resolved, when I gave embed everything including transitive as a directive to maven ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

It is a complex question by default.

1. Is the missing package included in JDK? Because if it is maybe you have to define for OSGi container with defining the missing package in the container config:

   ```
   org.osgi.framework.system.packages = \
       javax.accessibility,\
       javax.activity,\
       javax.crypto,\
       javax.crypto.interfaces,\
       …
       javax.wsdl.extensions,\
       org.xml.sax.helpers
   ```

   Or it can be defined as system extension bundle, which is a special fragment bundle. (Example with maven bundle plugin)

   ```
       <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <forceCreation>true</forceCreation>
               <archive>
                   <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                   <manifestEntries>
                       <Export-Package>com.sun.image.codec.jpeg</Export-Package>
                   </manifestEntries>
               </archive>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                   <phase>process-classes</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>manifest</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
               <instructions>
                   <Fragment-Host>system.bundle; extension:=framework</Fragment-Host>
               </instructions>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. Some other system already using it, maybe the bundle is also uploaded. For example ServiceMix already repackaged a lot of JAR as bundle, maybe you can find it. I use to be check with http://grepcode.com/, after I'm checking that the artifact in central is bundle or not.
3. When no bundle version is found, it can be the tricky part. Some of artifacts easy to osgify, because there is no classloader magic or reflection in there, on that case maven-shade plugin can be used to repackage the dependency as OSGi bundle. (in karaf you cab use the wrap feature)
4. If there is magic in bootstrapping very different and strange problems can be presented, where Dynamic-Import, Embed-Dependency, Required-Bunle and other not too OSGi ways can be used.

I'm not recommending the transitive dependency embedding. Instead of determinate which imports are requried and which is optional. For example JUnit tests are included on JAR but its not required for you, but when you are using transitive embed he whole JUnit will be included. Instrad of make instruction for maven bundle plugin for package for example:

````
Import-Package: org.junit.*;resolution:=optional```
````

or

```
Import-Pacage: !org.junit*
```

So As you see a lot of possible solution are presented and  there is no ultimate solution for that problem, a lot of factor are there.

Answer (score 0):

Try these out one by one:
1. Make sure the jar which contains these packages are deployed in karaf and are in active state.
2. Unresolved packages are added in pom under Import-Package.

Refer: [How to handle Import-Package entries which come from jars on the Bundle-Classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936310/how-to-handle-import-package-entries-which-come-from-jars-on-the-bundle-classpat)